# SSRS report shows me a Lot of empty space to the right hand side. (when you move the scroll bar to the right)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a report using the Report Builder tool.
But, when I exported with the MHTML option it shows me Lot of empty space to the right hand side. (**when you move the scroll bar to the right**)

Any ideas please, can you help? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a matrix report, you may also try setting the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true.  It is Report level property that you can find under "Other".

or else if it is a tabular report then adjust the margin and width accordingly.

Here the solution link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4a965d5c-0906-4690-a995-35aae594018c/how-to-avoid-empty-space-in-right-side-of-the-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required